# DENSE_RANK according to particular order

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, dense-rank

Hi I have a table of data I want to output the dense_rank of the names starting from the first group of names according to sorted dates order. e.g.

```
DROP TABLE MyTable
SELECT * INTO MyTable FROM (
  VALUES ('2015-12-23', 'ccc'),('2015-12-21', 'aaa'),
         ('2015-12-20', 'bbb'),('2015-12-22', 'aaa')
) t (date, name)
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY name) rank, * FROM MyTable ORDER BY date
```

For the query above I got

```
rank    date    name
2   2015-12-20  bbb
1   2015-12-21  aaa
1   2015-12-22  aaa
3   2015-12-23  ccc
```

You can see the dates are sorted (good), ranks are assigned to names in group (good), but the ranks do not start from the first group of name, e.g. I want

```
rank    date    name
1   2015-12-20  bbb
2   2015-12-21  aaa
2   2015-12-22  aaa
3   2015-12-23  ccc
```

How would you correct the query? If there are multiple working answers, the simplest/shortest one will be picked as the answer. Thanks.

### Added:

Thanks @lad2025 and @GiorgosBetsos for clarifying my question. Sorting is straightly according to dates and dates are unique in my case. Names can repeat and appear non-consecutively. So with `('2015-12-24', 'aaa')`, the output is

```
rank    date    name
1   2015-12-20  bbb
2   2015-12-21  aaa
2   2015-12-22  aaa
3   2015-12-23  ccc
4   2015-12-24  aaa
```

Comment: you have posted outputs both same

Comment: Where `('2015-12-24', 'aaa')` should go? (rank 2, after 2015-12-22) or rank 4?

Comment: What about additional rows like  `('2015-12-21',  'eee')` and `('2015-12-22',  'eee')` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY minGrpDate),
       [date], name
FROM (
  SELECT MIN([date]) OVER (PARTITION BY grp) AS minGrpDate,
         [date], name
  FROM (       
    SELECT [date], name,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [date])
           -
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY [date]) AS grp
    FROM mytable) AS t ) AS s
ORDER BY Date
```

**Explanation:**

- `grp` field identifies islands of consecutive records having the same `name`.
- `minGrpDate`, which is calculated using `grp`, is the minimum date of each island.
- Using `minGrpDate` we can now apply `DENSE_RANK()` to get required rank.

**Note1:** The above query handles discontinuities in `name` field, i.e. the case of non-consecutive fields having the same name.

**Note2:** The query does not handle the case of different `name` values sharing the same `date` value.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c5284/1)

Comment: If your actual data does not contain any discontinuities in `name` field then this solution is unnecessarily complex. @Giorgi's answer would be more suitable in that case

Comment: Thanks @GiorgosBetsos, this is what I need exactly. Although I can't comprehend your two row_number()s minusing each other, still I thought your answer is brilliant.

Answer (score 3):

First rank distinct names ordered by date and then join on the table:

```
;WITH cte AS(SELECT name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MIN(date)) rn 
             FROM dbo.MyTable 
             GROUP BY name)
SELECT c.rn, m.date, m.name
FROM cte c
JOIN dbo.MyTable m ON m.name = c.name
ORDER BY m.date
```

Comment: What if there is an additional row like `('2015-12-24', 'aaa')`?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos, it will have 2 as rank. OP has not mentioned what does he want in this case.

Comment: So, in that case dates will be unordered.

Comment: @user1589188, can you comment on Giorgos's comment?

Comment: Thanks @GiorgiNakeuri . Its interesting to see you have answered without using dense_rank. I wonder if it was my question that did not fit the purpose of dense_rank?