# rank a column with out ordering in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, rank, analytic-functions

I have the data as below, When I apply dense_rank by ordering id column, I am getting rank according to the order of integers but I need to rank as the records are displayed when run a query:

Data from query:

```
Rid   id

8100  161
8101   2
8102   2
8103   2
8104  156
```

When I apply dense_rank over order by id then I am getting

```
Rid   id    rank

8100  161    3
8101   2     1
8102   2     1
8103   2     1
8104  156    2
```

But my requirement is to get in below way:

```
Rid   id    rank

8100  161    1
8101   2     2
8102   2     2
8103   2     2
8104  156    3
```

Used row_number as well but the result is not as expected, not sure what option would be the better way.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Edit------------------------------

Query used

```
Select rid, id,dense_rank() over (order by id) row_num
from table
```

Comment: The query that you used would be of much help. Also, table structure would help. Cheers!

Comment: @VBokšić Thanks for reply, added query.

Comment: Have you tried : "(order by Rid, id)" ? I see that would not help. Sorry...

Comment: yes it just incremented rows adding 1 to every row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have adjusted solution from here: [DENSE_RANK according to particular order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34429903/dense-rank-according-to-particular-order) for your need.

I am not sure if I should mark this as duplicate because on this link above there is no ORACLE tag. If more experience members think I should please do comment and I will do so and delete this answer.

Here is the adjusted code and demo:

```
SELECT t2.rid
       , t2.id
       , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY t2.max_rid)
FROM (
  SELECT MAX(t1.rid) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.grupa) AS max_rid
         , t1.rid
         , t1.id
  FROM (       
    SELECT rid
           , id
           ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rid) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY rid) AS grupa
    FROM test_table) t1 )  t2
ORDER BY rid
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=319f4d86b3d81d0f4cb88d6eb9f86071)

Comment: You are welcome. Happy to be of any assistance. Do check the link where I have founded the answer from. It has some explanations and maybe you can vote up that answer to :) Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sum()` aggregation containing `(order by rid)` after getting the values from `lag()` analytic function within the first query

```
with tab( rid,id ) as
(
    select 8100,161 from dual union all              
    select 8101,2   from dual union all              
    select 8102,2   from dual union all              
    select 8103,2   from dual union all              
    select 8104,156 from dual
), t2 as 
   (
   select t.*, lag(id,1,0) over (order by rid) lg
     from tab t
   )
   select rid, id, sum(case when lg!=id then 1 else 0 end) over (order by rid) as row_num
     from t2
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=eacc0262c9de5f79f5ed07ce733cf939)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I am getting the resultset as a table output, can't hard code in query

Comment: you're welcome @Siva , butI cannot see any hardcoding.

Comment: I mean `select 8100,161 from dual` this part, I get `8100,161` as a result of query

Comment: @Siva - The WITH subquery just exists as a way to fake your table. It is a common technique on this site and other forums, to save the responders from needing to write `create table`, `insert` and `drop table` statements. It doesn't affect the validity of the solution.